# php cURL cookies/authentication not sticking?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am learning cURL in PHP, and need to authenticate to a web page, and store the session in a cookie.  I am able to log in just fine, but when I try to use the cookie to load another page, I don't get any output.  It's late, and I'm sure there's something stupid I'm missing, but I dont think I'll be able to sleep without this working..

```
$curl_p = curl_init($auth_url);
curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $svck);
curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$cres_auth = curl_exec($curl_p);

if(!preg_match("/Successful/i",$cres_auth))
    {
    ?><pre><?
            print_r("Login was unsuccessful.  URL passed was:");
    ?><br><br><?
            print_r($auth_url);
    ?></pre><?
    }else
    {
    ?><pre><?
            print_r("Login was successful.");
    ?></pre><?

    $curl_p = curl_init($data_url);
    curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $svck);
    curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_URL, $data_url);
    $cres_data = curl_exec($curl_p);
    echo $cres_data;
    }
```

Given the proper credentials, I get a "Login was successful", otherwise it fails.  If successful, I don't get anything else; do i need to do curl_close() and re-init?  Thanks!

edit

Not sure if it matters, but here is the header for the response when logging in normally (through a browser):

```
POST /admin HTTP/1.1
Host: url.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://url.com/admin?cmd=submit_logout
Cookie: svanoncollected=collected; password=4cf0ed4321adabbf46784e123a0316fb;     extension=4470;     iar=8123123f2b3e3541456cae084aeae77f; 
lang_locale=en_us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 96

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2011 07:43:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Fedora)
Set-Cookie: lang_locale=en_us; path=/
Set-Cookie: admin_pass=74927c9b91234d2ffb95e60fc832ffe0; path=/
Set-Cookie: admin_name=user; path=/
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

edit

I was logging into https://.. and did not include curl_setopt($curl_p, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); in the if().. block.  Adding it appears to have worked.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Is $svck pointing to a writeable file location ? Is the cookie created i.e. written to disk?

Comment: yes, files are being created; they appear as you would expec thtem to.

Comment: Probably the "CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE" is on the wrong place if you move it upwards it will most likely work. You need to set this opt outside of the preg_match block.